# Increase students marks average and make mark adjustement for every strudent

Tags: math

I feel really confused trying to make it correct, but I'm not sure what is the right method to resolve this.

Eg : I have 5 students with their exam mark respectively

```
average : (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 5 = 3.00
```

So now, I want to add `5` to the **average**

`new average : 3.00 + 5 = 8.00`

Question: How to adjust students mark depending on the **value** added to the **average**?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: It's taged as math ??? so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want equal distribution among students, add the cumulative increased sum 25(number of students(5)*increased value) in respective ratio to total marks of each student.

i.e.

```
For first student add (1/15)*25 to his marks
For second student add (2/15)*25 to his marks
For third student add (3/15)*25 to his marks and so on
```

Comment: I did not undestand from were you get 25. Is that just a tips. You mean (1/15)*5 + (2/15)*5 + (3/15)*5 + (4/15)*5 +(5/15) = 5. In this case what does 5 means

Comment: 25 is the cumulative sum you want to increase in order to increase the average to 8. That is equal to the average value being increased multiplied by the number of student.

Comment: So in this case what does the result her suppose to mean (1/15)*25 + (2/15)*25 + (3/15)*25 + (4/15)*25 +(5/15) *25 = 25. Sorry, I'm lost.

Comment: Yes by equally distributing 25 among students, you can increase the average value.  1st students' marks will be 1+(1/15)*25, 2nd students' marks will be 2+(2/15)*25 and so on.

Comment: Why you added 1+ , 2+ before every student, and also if this is how it works so what should be the general formula?

Comment: Let's generalize - 

Suppose marks of n students =  [m1,m2,m3...., mn]
Let's call the sum of these marks = `sum` (m1+m2+m3+...)
If you want to increase average by x marks - 

updated marks of students will be [ m1+n*x*(m1)/sum,  m2+n*x*(m2)/sum, ...]